# PHP mcrypt 3DES 168bytes key: encrypted string can't by decrypt by JAVA

Tags: java, php, encryption, 3des

I have a problem with 3DES of PHP. I'm doing a project that will access the internal interface of bank. They had developed an interface by java.
One function of the interface is that bank system will get the public RSA key from my server. The bank side is the client. He accesses my server by HTTP protocol. They required that the RSA public key was encrypted by 3DES. The key for 3DES is "1000000200YYMMDD".And they required the result to be sent back by byte stream.

I download several program of 3DES from web. They can get the encryped string. But they all failed at the bank side. The response is "string index out of range". I think this message is just the system message, and had few value for debug.
The following is my program.

I had several question about this problem.

**1, Many materail said that the length of 3DES key is max to 168 bytes. How can I extend my key to that length. I mean that the key of "1000000200YYMMDD" is just 16 chars, how to convert to 168bytes.**

**2, What is the difference of PHP and JAVA in 3DES encrypt.**

**3, Which block mode should I choose? ECB? CBC?**

**4, What kind of padding should I use?**

```
//encrypt method 1
public function DESencrypt($str)
{  
    if ($this->mcrypt == MCRYPT_DES) $str = $this->_pkcs5Pad($str);  
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size($this->mcrypt, $this->mode);  
    $pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);  
    $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);  
    $result = mcrypt_encrypt($this->mcrypt, base64_encode($this->des_key), $str, $this->mode);
    return $result;  
}  
//encrypt method 2

public function encrypt_1($input)
{  
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, '', 'ecb', '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->des_key, $iv);
    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    return $encrypted_data;
}
//encrypt method 3
function encrypt($str)  
{  
       $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);  
       $pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);  
       $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);  
       return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $this->des_key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);  
} 
//encrypt method 4
public function  encrypt_2($input)
{
    $key = $this->des_key.$this->des_key;
    $tripleKey = substr($key, 0, mcrypt_get_key_size($this->mcrypt, $this->mode));
    $blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size($this->mcrypt, $this->mode);
    $paddingSize = $blocksize - (strlen($input) % $blocksize);
    $input .= str_repeat(chr($paddingSize), $paddingSize);
    $encodedText = mcrypt_encrypt($this->mcrypt, $tripleKey, $input, $this->mode);
    return $encodedText;
}


///the main function
$des_key="1000000200YYMMDD";
///Initialize the encrypt class
$c = new Xcrypt($des_key);
/// Set the encrypt algorithm to 3DES
$c->setMcrypt(MCRYPT_3DES);
/// Get the RSA public key
$pub = $c->get_ZGSC_public();
// here I will encrypt the RSA key, I had used all the four method above, but all failed
$encyt_pub = $c->encrypt_2($pub);
///return to the client in byte stream.
file_put_contents("php://output", getBytes(base64_encode($encyt_pub)));
```

Comment: 1. you provide the key so its up to you what length it is. its padded for you if to short

Comment: Is `1000000200YYMMDD` the actual key or is `YYMMDD` substituted with the date, e.g. `1000000200140925`? For many of your other questions, the answer has to come from your client - ask them what padding they expect, what cipher mode they want you to use. Also ask if they want two-key or three-key 3DES.

Comment: The exact information I have is they use three-key 3DES. And the 'YYMMDD' is changed according to current date but just 6 chars not eight ones, like 140925, not 20140925. I can not get more surpport from bank because the surpporter did not know nearly every thing. What i can do is try each mode,each padding method . I am not very familiar with the theory of encrypt. So I am not sure what I had done was right.